# Matlab, how to loop through a series of pushbuttons?

Tags: matlab, loops, matlab-figure

My program creates 5 pushbuttons, and I need to change their color according to the values in a matrix A. So I define A in the main, and then at the end of main I call the function create_maze(A).

The following is create_maze(A):

```
function create_maze(A)
A

% create 5X5 pushbuttons

scr = get(0, 'screensize');
f1 = figure(1);
set(f1, 'menubar', 'none');
set(f1, 'position', [scr(1) scr(2) scr(3) scr(4)]);

h1 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'ForegroundColor', 'blue',...
    'Position', [200 200 100 100],...
    'Callback', pushbutton1_Callback);
h2 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'ForegroundColor', 'blue',...
    'Position', [300 200 100 100],...
    'Callback', pushbutton1_Callback);
h3 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'ForegroundColor', 'blue',...
    'Position', [400 200 100 100],...
    'Callback', pushbutton1_Callback);
h4 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'ForegroundColor', 'blue',...
    'Position', [500 200 100 100],...
    'Callback', pushbutton1_Callback);
h5 = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
    'ForegroundColor', 'blue',...
    'Position', [600 200 100 100],...
    'Callback', pushbutton1_Callback);

function [L] = pushbutton1_Callback(h0object, A)
    % here I put the pushbuttons together in an array
    L=[h1, h2, h3, h4, h5];
for i = 1:size(A,1)
    if i == 0
    set(L{i},'Backgroundcolor','w');
    elseif i == 1
    set(L{i},'Backgroundcolor','b');
    elseif i == 2
    set(L{1},'Backgroundcolor','g');
    elseif i == 2
    set(L{i},'Backgroundcolor','y');
    end
end
end
end
```

Unfortunately I get:

```
Error using create_maze/pushbutton1_Callback (line 164)
Not enough input arguments.
```

Could anybody help me with this loop?
Thank you!

Comment: You are not outputting anything in `pushbutton1_Callback`, thus `L` is utterly unused. Try setting `function [L]=pushbutton1_Callback(h0object, A)`

Comment: Thanks, I tried but it says `Undefined function or variable "h1"`

Comment: Well, that's a clear message isn't it? Define `h1`. I guess it's coming out of your `h0object`, but you need to explicitly tell MATLAB that.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't `h1` already defined as GUI object as the top of the page?

Comment: Not inside your function... Pass it to the function in that case.

Comment: Hi, I solved the h1 problem and used your suggestion (I edited the code in the question as well), but now I get a different error message: `Error using create_maze/pushbutton1_Callback (line 164)
Not enough input arguments.`

Comment: I think you should give `pushbutton1_Callback` more inputs when you call it then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about the scope of functions
Any variables defined within a function that aren't output by it will be cleaned up (deleted) when the function finishes executing.

In the case of graphics objects a link to the push button handles will still actually exist somewhere as a child of the main figure window, but it will be mush easier if you output the handles somehow from 'create_maze'

it is safer to define the line

L=[h1, h2, h3, h4, h5];

at the end of create_maze, rather than trying to be tricky with nested functions which will give you limited advantage here, and possibly slight overhead.

Check out the mathworks website for more info on the scope of variables in nested functions, but to be on the safe side, be sure that all of functions could run without relying on the other having defined variables.

Ie. make sure functions only need their input variables